# Asymptotic complexity of building a binary tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, asymptotic-complexity

What is the complexity of **building** a balanced binary tree of size n from scratch?

Node insertion is O(log n).

However, as you go along, the cumulative time is

O( (log 1) + (log 2) + ... + (log (n-1)) + (log n) ).

What does this "add up" to?

It is o(n log(n)), *small 'o'*, i don't know how far small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`log(1) + log(2) + ... + log(n) = log(1*2*..*n) = log(n!)` which is in `Theta(nlogn)`

So, building a (balanced) tree from scratch has a tight asymptotic bound of `Theta(nlogn)`

---

**EDIT:**

I also wanted to show you a proof that you cannot build a BST better than `O(nlogn)` with any algorithm. Basically - this is because it will allow sorting better than `O(nlogn)` by simply building your tree with the 'better' algorithm, and then - doing in-order traversal on the tree and outputting elements. The result will be a sorted array.

Complexity in-order traversal is `O(n)`, and since assuming the tree is built faster then `O(nlogn)` - we get contradiction to the fact that sorting is `Omega(nlogn)` problen.